# No boot after reseting bios to default, Ubuntu partition gone

Tags: boot, uefi, bios, restore, default

I set my bios to their default settings in order to try and boot a Lubuntu Live-cd but something I didn't consider is that it would wipe out my Ubuntu boot-entries. The only option I have now is an (empty) UEFI-boot.

Does anyone know how I can restore this?

Big thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you correctly, all you did was reset the bios settings, aka CMOS, which is on the motherboard.  Unless there's more I don't understand, that should not have deleted an "entries".

I suspect that what has actually happened is that resetting your CMOS changed the default boot sequence so that your computer is attempting to boot to some other attached drive, such as a blank SD card or USB flash drive you left plugged in.  This same difficulty happened to a friend of mine about three months ago.  We have yet to understand her USB's partition had become configured as bootable.

Comment: It does not try to boot from another device, it tries to boot from the part of my HDD that does not contain any OS. Somewhere on that HDD Ubuntu is installed, but is now unable to boot since I set my bios back to the default settings. See pic for boot options, Ubuntu was above that option before the reset:

http://i57.tinypic.com/156fktj.jpg

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure but it sounds like you just need to change the BIOS settings from UEFI to legacy boot?

If not maybe this post can help you?

[Is it still possible to install Ubuntu to an external harddrive with UEFI?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/559007/is-it-still-possible-to-install-ubuntu-to-an-external-harddrive-with-uefi)